# Specification.where().and() behaving unexpectedly in query by specification spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm trying to perform a search across multiple attributes in query by specification in Spring Boot. When I enter one word to search for, it works but when I enter two words, it doesn't provide the correct output.

Here's the model.

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Person {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private long id;
    
    private String firstName;
    
    private String surName;
    
    private int age;
    
    private Date dob;
    
    private String description;
    
    private String highestEducationQualification;
    
    private String occupation;
    
    private String employer;
    
    private String college;
    
    private String school;
    
    private String eyecolor;
    
    private double weight;
    
    private double height;
    
    private boolean driversLicence;
    
    private boolean provisionalLicence;

    private long phoneNumber;
    
    private char gender;
    
    private String emailAddress;
    
    private String websiteAddress;
    
    private String homeAddress;
    
    private String image;
    
}
```

Here's the repo.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {
    List<Person> searchByFirstNameContainingOrSurNameContainingAllIgnoreCase(String firstName, String surName);
    
    Person findByFirstName(String firstName);
    List<Person> searchByFirstNameContainingAllIgnoreCase(String firstName, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchBySurNameContainingAllIgnoreCase(String surName, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByAge(int age, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByDescriptionContainingAllIgnoreCase(String desc, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByHighestEducationQualificationContainingAllIgnoreCase(String edu, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByOccupationContainingAllIgnoreCase(String occ, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByEmployerContainingAllIgnoreCase(String emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByCollegeContainingAllIgnoreCase(String emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchBySchoolContainingAllIgnoreCase(String emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByEyecolorContainingAllIgnoreCase(String eye, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByWeight(double weight, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByHeight(double height, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByDriversLicence(boolean emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByProvisionalLicence(boolean emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByPhoneNumber(long phone, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByGender(char emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByEmailAddressIgnoreCase(String emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByWebsiteAddressContainingAllIgnoreCase(String emp, Pageable page);
    List<Person> searchByHomeAddressContainingAllIgnoreCase(String emp, Pageable page);
}
```

Here's the service.

```
public List<Person> searchBySpecAll(String search, String page, String num, String sortBy, String ascending){
        ArrayList<PersonSpecification> personSpecs = new ArrayList<PersonSpecification>();
        
        ArrayList<String> searchWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        
        for(String s : search.split(" ")) {
            searchWords.add(s);
        }
        
        int numWords = searchWords.size();
        
        System.out.println("num words");
        
        
        for(String s : searchWords) {
            System.out.println(s);
            
            int age = 0;
            
             try {
                 age = Integer.parseInt(s);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 
             }
             double d = 0;
             try {
                 d = Double.parseDouble(s);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 
             }
             
            
             char gender = 0;
             try {
                 gender = search.charAt(0);
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 
             }
             
             
             PersonSpecification spec = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("firstName", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec2 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("surName", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec3 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("age", ":", age));
             PersonSpecification spec4 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("description", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec5 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("highestEducationQualification", "=", s));
             PersonSpecification spec6 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("occupation", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec7 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("employer", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec8 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("college", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec9 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("school", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec10 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("eyecolor", "=", s));
             PersonSpecification spec11 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("weight", "=", d));
             PersonSpecification spec12 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("height", "=", d));
             PersonSpecification spec17 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("phoneNumber", "=", d));
             //PersonSpecification spec18 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("gender", "=", gender));
             PersonSpecification spec19 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("emailAddress", "=", s));
             PersonSpecification spec20 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("websiteAddress", ":", s));
             PersonSpecification spec21 = new PersonSpecification(new SearchCriteria("homeAddress", ":", s));;
             
             personSpecs.add(spec);
             personSpecs.add(spec2);
             personSpecs.add(spec3);
             //personSpecs.add(spec4);
             //personSpecs.add(spec5);
             personSpecs.add(spec6);
             personSpecs.add(spec7);
             personSpecs.add(spec8);
             personSpecs.add(spec9);
             personSpecs.add(spec10);
             personSpecs.add(spec11);
             personSpecs.add(spec12);
             personSpecs.add(spec17);
             //personSpecs.add(spec18);
             personSpecs.add(spec19);
             personSpecs.add(spec20);
             personSpecs.add(spec21);
        }
        
         int pageNum = 0;
         try {
             pageNum = Integer.parseInt(page);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             
         }
         
         int numResults = 0;
         try {
             numResults = Integer.parseInt(num);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             
         }
         boolean asc = true;
         if(ascending.equals("false"))
             asc = false;
         
        
        Pageable firstPageWithFourElements = PageRequest.of(pageNum, numResults, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.DESC, sortBy));;
        
         if(asc) {
             firstPageWithFourElements = PageRequest.of(pageNum, numResults, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, sortBy));
         } 
         
         ArrayList<Specification<Person>> specs = new ArrayList<Specification<Person>>();
         
         Specification<Person> specTotal = null;
         
         int numSpecs = 14;
         
         int iters = personSpecs.size() / numSpecs; 
         
         System.out.println(personSpecs.size());
         
         System.out.println("Iterations of personSpecs: " + iters);
        
         
         for(int i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
             specs.add(Specification.where(personSpecs.get(i)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 1)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 2)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 3)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 4)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 5)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 6)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 7)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 8)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 9)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 10)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 11)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 12)).or(personSpecs.get(i + 13)));
         }
         System.out.println("Number of specifications to append to total: " + specs.size());
         
         int totalToAppend = 0;
         totalToAppend = specs.size();
         
         System.out.print(totalToAppend);
         
         switch(totalToAppend) {
            case 1: {
                specTotal = specs.get(0); 
                System.out.println(1 + " case");
                break;
            }
            case 2: {
                specTotal = Specification.where(specs.get(0).and(specs.get(1))); 
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                specTotal = Specification.where(specs.get(0).and(specs.get(1)).and(specs.get(2)));  
                break;
            }
            case 4: {
                specTotal = Specification.where(specs.get(0).and(specs.get(1)).and(specs.get(2)).and(specs.get(3)));  
                break;
            }
         }
         
         //specTotal = Specification.where(spec).or(spec2).or(spec3).or(spec6).or(spec7).or(spec8).or(spec9).or(spec11).or(spec12).or(spec19).or(spec21).or(spec20).or(spec4).or(spec5).or(spec10).or(spec17);
         
         Page<Person> results = personRepo.findAll(specTotal, firstPageWithFourElements);
        
        
         List<Person> res = results.getContent();
         
         return res;
    }
```

You will notice, the function works by splitting the query into words if necessary. Iterates each word creating an arraylist of specifications for each word. Then it created two `Specification.where()` by accessing the previously created specifications in the arraylist and combines them in a switch, depending on the number of words that creates total `Specification.where()`.
specification depending on how many words were entered. There is also support for pagination, sort and sort direction. When I enter one word, it works fine. But when I enter two words it gives me incorrect output. It shows another person with a surname containing the search query word entered.

E.g.

When I enter "Adam" as a search query, it shows me my person data. But when I enter "Adam Howard" it shows me someone else with the name Edi Adamiec. I would like for data for Adam Howard to be outputted. I've tried using .or()`` in the "case 2 switch" instead of and but that's not the functionality I'm aiming for. The name Edi Adamiec, comes from dummy data in the database, which I used a dummy data generator for. I could provide the database data, if needed, just let me know. Please, your help is appreciated.

Here's the generated SQL.

```
Hibernate: select person0_.user_id as user_id1_0_, person0_.age as age2_0_, person0_.college as college3_0_, person0_.description as descript4_0_, person0_.dob as dob5_0_, person0_.drivers_licence as drivers_6_0_, person0_.email_address as email_ad7_0_, person0_.employer as employer8_0_, person0_.eyecolor as eyecolor9_0_, person0_.first_name as first_n10_0_, person0_.gender as gender11_0_, person0_.height as height12_0_, person0_.highest_education_qualification as highest13_0_, person0_.home_address as home_ad14_0_, person0_.image as image15_0_, person0_.occupation as occupat16_0_, person0_.phone_number as phone_n17_0_, person0_.provisional_licence as provisi18_0_, person0_.school as school19_0_, person0_.sur_name as sur_nam20_0_, person0_.website_address as website21_0_, person0_.weight as weight22_0_ from person person0_ where (person0_.first_name like ? or person0_.home_address like ? or person0_.website_address like ? or person0_.email_address=? or person0_.phone_number=0 or person0_.height=0.0 or person0_.weight=0.0 or person0_.eyecolor=? or person0_.school like ? or person0_.college like ? or person0_.employer like ? or person0_.occupation like ? or person0_.age=0 or person0_.sur_name like ?) and (person0_.home_address like ? or person0_.website_address like ? or person0_.email_address=? or person0_.phone_number=0 or person0_.height=0.0 or person0_.weight=0.0 or person0_.eyecolor=? or person0_.school like ? or person0_.college like ? or person0_.employer like ? or person0_.occupation like ? or person0_.age=0 or person0_.sur_name like ? or person0_.first_name like ?) order by person0_.first_name asc limit ?
```

I effectively want to search across all attributes with some attributes being a single word, to paragraphs of text. I want the search query to be broken up into words so it can search by firstname and surname for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you add disjuctions like `person0_.weight=0.0` which are true for some other people. Try removing these.

Comment: It's a good thought, but the data for the other person that is showing up doesn't align with your suggestion. There's no values of 0 for weight or height or any other number attribute.

Comment: What parameters are you binding? Did you check if some of the parameters for the like predicates might match multiple rows?

Comment: Even if the like predicate returns multiple rows it should not be a problem. I have received multiple results from the beginning and there might be an event where the search returns multiple people so it should be part of the functionality. But I can't see what's causing the corrupted results, it's probably something so obvious. I forgot the add the specification, I can show you the github repo, if you have the time to take a look.

Comment: https://github.com/mupml/person-search-spring-boot-vue-security

Comment: I would recommend you look at the generated SQL queries along with bound parameters and play around with that to see what is wrong in the logic. From a quick look, I can tell that you connect specifications in a wrong way i.e. you should use `(attr1 = ? OR attr2 = ?) AND (attr1 = ? OR attr2 = ?)` to have a conjunct per search word.

Comment: Thanks Christian, I will look into it.